# Arrays.asList(array).contains(value) doesn't work correctly (android)

Tags: android, arrays

I have a string[]

```
String [] example = new String[]{
"one",
"two",
"three",
"four"
}
```

i am trying to check if this array contain next string "one", but it return false...
Here is my code:

```
boolean check = Arrays.asList(example).contains("one");
```

any ideas why it happens?

Comment: one explanation would be if your string contained non-printable characters, making the strings effectively different. test the truth value of `example[0].equals("one");`

Comment: Ya just tested this works fine interesting.

Comment: @njzk2: can you please give us a brief explanation on this why it is not working as mentioned in the question

Comment: I just ran a test on my machine, the code you have above is working for me. Since `example[0].equals("one")` is working for you, I would double check that the array you are passing into `Arrays.asList()` is the one you intend (i.e. that it is `example` and not, say `args` from your main function definition).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Javadoc for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) at the contains method you will see that it uses the equals() method to evaluate if two objects are the same.

Make test:

```
List<String> list =  Arrays.asList(example);
boolean check = list.contains(list.get(1));
```

and

```
List<String> list =  Arrays.asList(example);
boolean check = list.contains("one");
```

Comment: the reason i guess was that inferred type argument was not defined.

Comment: the inferred type is not relevant.

Comment: You are comparing references to the object not string primitive.

Answer (score 0):

As this code is correct I guess that at the time/point of using this code your Array may have not been initialized yet or it's contents may have been altered.

Also try a clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is somehow related to the fact, that `Arrays.asList()` returns special implementation of List - `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, and not the `java.util.ArrayList`.